# Resolving power of telescope and circular aperture

Tags: geometric-optics, diffraction, lenses, telescopes

From the formula of circular aperture we get:
sinθ=1.22λ/D
But according to this formula, the θ is the angle on the side of the Airy disc formed.

The formula for angle of resolution for a human eye seeing a hair on the ground or seeing 2 stars through a telescope is also the same, ie:
sinθ=1.22λ/D
But in the case of the human eye and telescope, we consider the angle θ to be the angle subtended by the stars or the human hair in the eye lens. Whereas the actual formula for circular aperture is applicable when the angle is considered to be the radius of the Airy disc. Though the two θ in the above formula are different but the formula remains the same.
Moreover, in the case of the telescope, we are actually applying this formula in the source's side but the actual formula is applicable only towards the image side/ Airy disc side.

Can someone please help me with and tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you state your question more clearly?

Comment: Actually I want to say that in the case of circular aperture the angle considered is subtended by the Airy disc of the image formed whereas in the case of telescope we consider the angle subtended by the object and not the image of it. How is this possible?

Comment: In the first case, the angle is on the image side whereas in the second case, ie the case of telescope the angle is on the object side. Shouldn't it be on the image side?

Comment: Notice that the Rayleigh criterion uses two point objects not one extended object. The angular separation between them can be stated in terms of either the object side or the image side--they are the same

Comment: oh...so we can use the angle subtended interchangeably. I thought the angle taken should be on the image's side and not on the object side's. Thanks a lot, @user45664 :)

Comment: Indeed, for a telescope or a distant object, they are the same angles.
This would not be the case for a microscope! In this case, the angle at which the entrance pupil is viewed from the object plane must be taken into account.  And this is not the angular width of the emerging beam. (Which would be used to calculate the width of the Airy spot)

Answer (score 1):

RAYLEIGH CRITERION:  $\theta - \lambda/D$

> 'The diffraction limit to resolution states that two images are just
> resolvable when the center of the diffraction pattern of one is
> directly over the first minimum of the diffraction pattern (Airy disc) of the other.'

So the angle the two imaged point objects diffraction patterns subtends at the aperture is $\theta$ which is the same as the angle the centers of the imaged point objects make with each other when the first minimum of one diffraction pattern is aligned with the other's maximum per Rayleigh.

Comment: Do you have any source or diagram to support this statement:---"So the angle the two imaged point objects diffraction patterns subtends at the aperture is θ which is the same as the angle the centers of the imaged point objects make with each other when the first minimum of one diffraction pattern is aligned with the other's maximum per Rayleigh."?

Comment: Its just my interpetation of the previous quote.

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67CoKmyT9xg) by Prof. M. R. Shenoy beautifully explains everything related to resolving powers and limits of telescopes and microscopes.

Your doubt is explained at around *T*$=20:56$ .

This screenshot/diagram should clear everything up.

[image]